# How does numpy.histogram2d() work?

Tags: python, numpy, histogram2d

While reading up on numpy, I encountered the function **numpy.histogram2d()**.

What is it for and how does it work? and how to understand the first returned parameter H ?

reference: [numpy.histogram2d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html)

Comment: You should complete the example in the help topic to see its graphical representation.